# jquery button trigger input filed directly

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/kkadso/m43acyfu/)

As you can see, click the button `month` , it will appear a input filed.
Then click the input filed, you can choose month

I want to know how to trigger the month picker directly when click the `month` button
whithout click the input field again but not works well:

```
$("#Btn").click(function () {                                     
    $("#month").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking but I suspect what you are looking for is `$('#month').focus()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $("#Btn").click(function () {                 
                    $(".test").show();
                    $("#month").trigger("focus");
                });
```

monthpicker uses `focus` event, it seems, not click.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m43acyfu/2/